# Return all values for an API request from the NPPES NPI database

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch

I am using the below code to retrieve doctors medical information after inputting their NPI number into Google Sheets.

So far, I have managed to return the phone number and fax number, but I want to either return all entries (name, address, license code etc etc).
OR to return their first name, last name, address, fax and phone number.

Can anyone assist me?

```
/**
Google AppScript for validating an NPI
Returns specialty and Address
if NPI is valid US MD w/ associated license
Note uses primary taxonomy and practice location
**/

function validateNPI(npi) {

let nppes = 'https://npiregistry.cms.hhs.gov/api/?number=__NPI__&version=2.1';
var r = JSON.parse(
UrlFetchApp.fetch(nppes.replace('__NPI__', npi)).getContentText());

if(r.Errors || !(entry = r.results[0])) // no such NPI
return "Not a valid active NPI";

if(entry.enumeration_type !== 'NPI-1') // not type 1 individual NPI
return "Not an individual, type 1 NPI";

if( (addr = entry.addresses.filter(a => a.address_purpose == 'LOCATION')[0])
.country_code !== 'US')
return "Not based in US";

return [[
addr.telephone_number, addr.fax_number
]];
;
}
```

Comment: I would need to see the returned JSON

Comment: Welcome to [so]. "Can someone assist me?" is not an actual question. Ref [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1595451). Please [edit] the question to add more details, i.e. how the function is called show the API response. Tip: Add console.log(r) after `var r = ...`  and add the execution logs to the question.